# PHP strtotime inconsistency between servers

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

Today I notice this about unix times:

```
//on my local or any web servers that i work on Brazil
echo strtotime('2016-07-04'); //return  1467601200

//on phptester.net or any other like it
echo strtotime('2016-07-04'); //return  1467590400
```

Whats happening here? 
It is not suppose to be equal?

Comment: that would depend on the php instance's default **[time zone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)**

Comment: The difference between the two numbers is exactly 3 x 3600 seconds. In what time zone you are?

Comment: anytime you have time differences that are some even multiple of 3600 seconds, it's almost always a time-zone issue.

Comment: @Marc B: Be aware, there are a few countries which are 30mins off the hour, some regions even 15mins!

Comment: yeah, but 3600/1hr is most common.

Comment: @Marc B: Now doubt, that's true. But I travelled to one of such 30min countries, so I'm aware of their existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a gander at the PHP time documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) you'll see that php time counts the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).  The 0th second of a day in one timezone is different than the 0th second of the day in another timezone, and different php instances may use different timezones.

Comment: Hm. That new for me. I always thought that the same date give the same timestamp in every place of the world. So if i get timestamps create on different places of the world I´ll get inconsistent results? I always thought that the reason for unixtime was to everyone communicate dates in the same way. 

But in fact echo strtotime('1970-01-01'); give me 10800, which is super weird to me.

Comment: It's not inconsistent, it just means you need more information.  It's kind of like asking a person what time it is.  You can ask your php instance with date_default_timezone_get().  I'm fairly certain if you use that on your local instance and also on the remote instance, you'll find a timezone difference that equals exactly the numerical difference you're seeing.